# RecyclerView - Loading Pictures From Web

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, picasso

I am trying to make a small app, that gets random pictures and movies of dogs and displays them in a recycle view. I am using Picasso for loading the pictures from URLs

The way I want it designed is that each picture gets displayed on its own (taking up the whole recyclerview) and when the user scrolls up or down he sees the previous or next image respectively.

Currently, I just use an AsyncTask to grab 10 images from https://random.dog/woof.json, load them to an `ArrayList` and move the data to the adapter. Not working as intended at the moment (Multiple images into the space where I want only one to show, and for some strange reason my AsyncTask gets called repeatedly even though I only call it from my MainActivity)

**Code for the adapter:**

```
public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.DogViewHolder> {

public ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();
public Context mContext;


public RecycleViewAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}


@Override
public DogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    int layoutForListItems = R.layout.list_items;
    LayoutInflater inflater =LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutForListItems, null);
    return new DogViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final DogViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String url = null;
    if (urlList != null) {
        url = urlList.get(position);
    }
    if (url != null) {
        String imageType = url.substring(url.length() - 4);

        View v = new View(mContext);

        Log.d("##############", "IMAGE TYPE - " + imageType);

        switch (imageType) {
            case ".mp4":
                Log.d("########", "movie url - " + url);
                holder.mVidView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
                holder.mVidView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mVidView.requestFocus();
                holder.mVidView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        holder.mVidView.start();
                    }
                });
                holder.mVidView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                        Log.d("########", "Error playing movie...");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                break;
            default:
                Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(holder.mImgView);
                holder.mImgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }
    else {
        Log.d("###############", "url was null");
        holder.mImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image_found);
        holder.mImgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (urlList == null) { return 0; }
    return urlList.size();
}

public void updateData(ArrayList<String> newList) {
    urlList.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class DogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final VideoView mVidView;
    private final ImageView mImgView;

    private DogViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mVidView = (VideoView) v.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        mImgView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_view);

    }
}
```

}

**AsyncTask Code:** (gets called in OnCreate)

```
public class AsyncTaskThingy extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
            urlList.add(DogGrabber.getUrlFromJson());
        }
        return urlList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> data) {
        mAdapter.updateData(data);
        super.onPostExecute(data);
        declareReady();
    }
```

Been picking at this for a few hours, when I add .fit() to Picasso load method nothing displays at all.

Thought I'd include my XML files aswell:

**Main Activity layout file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">



<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



</LinearLayout>
```

And the RecyclerView items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
<VideoView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: make linearlayout height to match_parent

Comment: Tried that previously, no go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the layout manager. Unlike list view, recycler view requires a layout manager.

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

See the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html).

Comment: I do that in my onCreate method in the MainActivity.